# IBM IMM2: Which level to control power and have remote terminal access

Tags: remote-access, ibm, electrical-power, ibm-xseries

We're looking to purchase an entry level System X server, specifically the x3100 M4. What I've been unable to figure out is what the lowest level of IMM2 we need is in order to remote the system regardless of power state, and of course control the power state itself. The IMM2 user manual only confuses matters by stating that:

"[...]All levels provide the following:
- Around-the-clock remote access and management of your server
- Remote management independent of the status of the managed server
- Remote control of hardware and operating systems."

But on the other hand, only from IMM2 Standard (not Basic) does it feature "Telnet and ssh CLI"

What's the right answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IBM System x3100 M4, You have to upgrade IMM2 from Basic to Standard, then Upgrade standard to Advance. You can refer this link for IMM2 Feature and upgrade option. 
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/tips0849.html